# ¿Por que el return no devuelve el valor correcto?

Tags: javascript

Quiero retornar el valor del `console`, pero no retorna nada.

Este es mi código:

```js
function findOutlier(integers) {
  let odd = integers[0];

  integers.forEach(function(current) {

    if (odd % 2 == 0) {
      if (current % 2 > 0) {
        console.log(current);// ESTE VALOR
        return current;
      }
    } else {
      if (current % 2 == 0) {
        return current;
      }
    }
  });
}

console.log(findOutlier([2, 6, 8, 10, 3]));
```

Mi ejercicio es:

> You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but
>   could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely
>   comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers
>   except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as
>   an argument and returns this "outlier" N.
>
> Examples [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36] Should return: 11 (the only
>   odd number)
>
> [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21] Should return: 160 (the only even
>   number)

Trato de obtener estos resultados:

```
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([0, 1, 2]), 1)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([1, 2, 3]), 2)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([2,6,8,10,3]), 3)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([0,0,3,0,0]), 3)
Test.assertEquals(findOutlier([1,1,0,1,1]), 0)
```

Comment: ¿Buscas obtener solo el primer resultado que cumpla la condición o todos?

Comment: @Marcos exactamente!!!

Comment: ¿Exactamente cual de las 2?

Comment: @Marcos el return esta en los dos casos, el algoritmo esta bien, lo que no entiendo es porque no retorna?

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener solo el primero que cumpla alguna des las condiciónes o TODOS los que cumplen las condiciones?

Comment: Qué intentas hacer con esto? `odd % 2`. Estás dividiendo el arreglo entero entre un número, eso te dara `NaN - No es un número`

Comment: @egallardo, `odd`, es igual al primer elemento del arreglo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), sirve para:

> ejecutar la función indicada una vez por cada elemento del array.
> **Valor devuelto**: `undefined`.

### Solución:

Para obtener solo el primer resultado que cumple la condición podrías usar [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function findOutlier(integers) {
  let odd = integers[0];

  return integers.find(function(current) {

    if (odd % 2 == 0) {
      if (current % 2 > 0) {
        return current;
      }
    } else {
      if (current % 2 == 0) {
        return current;
      }
    }
  }) || 0; // Si no encontramos ninguno
}

console.log(findOutlier([2, 6, 8, 10, 3]), 3);
console.log(findOutlier([0, 1, 2]), 1)
console.log(findOutlier([1, 2, 3]), 2)
console.log(findOutlier([2,6,8,10,3]), 3)
console.log(findOutlier([0,0,3,0,0]), 3)
console.log(findOutlier([1,1,0,1,1]), 0);
```

---

## Update

Como ha comentado @egallardo, tu método no funciona para todos los casos.
Esta podrías ser una mejor solución:

```js
function findOutlier(integers) {
  // Buscamos todos los numeros pares
  let even = integers.filter(a => a % 2 === 0);
  // Si solo encontramos 1, lo devolvemos, sino buscamos el impar
  return even.length === 1 ? even[0] : integers.find(a => a % 2);
}

console.log(findOutlier([2, 6, 8, 10, 3]), 3);
console.log(findOutlier([0, 1, 2]), 1)
console.log(findOutlier([1, 2, 3]), 2)
console.log(findOutlier([2, 6, 8, 10, 3]), 3)
console.log(findOutlier([0, 0, 3, 0, 0]), 3)
console.log(findOutlier([1, 1, 0, 1, 1]), 0);
console.log(findOutlier([9,2,8,6,4]), 9); // Caso comentado
```

Comment: porque debo poner doble return, en la funcion find y en las condiciones if

Comment: @hubman, el primero (`eg: return integers.find(...`), es para indicar el valor retornado por la función `findOutlier`. El segundo es para indicarle a la funcion `find`, cual es el valor correcto y que debe dejar de buscar. **PD**: El segundo `return` estaba, pero en una de las ediciones lo borraste

Comment: si estaba pero lo ponia por costumbre, ahora ya aprendi el porque, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @hubman Ten en cuenta que esta función no soluciona el problema. No va a encontrar el `outlier` en este caso: `findOutlier([9,2,8,6,4]);`

Comment: @hubman, he actualizado mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Esto es más corto y funciona en todos los casos.

```js
var findOutlier = (arr, f = 0) => {
 arr.forEach(c => c%2 === 0 ? ++f : f);
 return f > 1 ? arr.find(n => n%2 !== 0) : arr.find(n => n%2 === 0);
};



console.log(findOutlier([160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]));
console.log(findOutlier([9,2,8,6,4]));
console.log(findOutlier([2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]));
```